# RANKX Continuation

Tags: powerbi, dax

I am trying to create a rank by growth where sales are greater than 100, and if they are less than that the rank would continue on from the previous.

```
IF (
    [Sales] >= 100,
    RANKX (
        FILTER (
            ALL ( Sales[customer] ),
            [Sales] >= 100
        ),
        [Sales Growth],
        ,
        DESC
    ),
    
    // I want this section below to continue the rank not start over back at 1
    RANKX (
        FILTER (
            ALL ( Sales[customer] ),
            [Sales] < 100
        ),
        [Sales Growth],
        ,
        DESC
    )
)
```

Comment: Maybe add the count of distinct customers with sales >=100 to the second index.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You calculate the MAX rank of the >= 100 condition and then add that to the result of FALSE branch.

Try this:

```
Something =
VAR AllCustomers =
    ALL ( Sales[customer] )
RETURN
    IF (
        [Sales] >= 100,
        RANKX ( FILTER ( AllCustomers, [Sales] >= 100 ), [Sales Growth],, DESC ),
        VAR MaxGTRank =
            MAXX (
                AllCustomers,
                RANKX ( FILTER ( AllCustomers, [Sales] >= 100 ), [Sales Growth],, DESC )
            )
        VAR LTRank =
            RANKX (
                FILTER ( ALL ( Sales[customer] ), [Sales] < 100 ),
                [Sales Growth],
                ,
                DESC
            )
        RETURN
            LTRank + MaxGTRank
    )
```